# parâmetros de função struct

Tags: c, struct, syntax-error

Estou fazendo um código que calcula a soma e a subtração de números complexos, porém, não consigo encontrar o erro para conseguir compilar.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
typedef struct NI {
    float real;
    float imag;
}complexo;
float soma(float z.real,float z.imag,float w.real,float w.imag){
complexo z,w,s;
    s.real=z.real+w.real;
    s.imag=z.imag+w.imag; 
    printf("%f + %f",s.real,s.imag);
    printf("i\n");
   return s.real,s.imag;
}
float produto(float z.real,float z.imag,float w.real,float w.imag){
complexo z,w,m;
    m.real = z.real*w.real - z.imag*w.imag;
    m.imag = z.real*w.imag + z.imag*w.real;
    printf("%f + %f",m.real,m.imag);
    printf("i\n");
return m.real,m.imag;
}
int main(){
complexo z,w,s,m;
char op;

    scanf("%f %f %c %f %f",&z.real, &z.imag, &op, &w.real, &w.imag);

    if(op=='+'){
        soma(z.real,z.imag,w.real,w.imag);
    }
    if(op=='*'){
        produto(z.real,z.imag,w.real,w.imag);
    }


return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Passe a estrutura como parâmetro. Veja: https://ideone.com/VvWTlG

Answer (score -1):

Vou separar a explicação em duas parte, erros na lógica(1) e erros na sintaxe da linguagem C(2):

(1) Grande parte da lógica de seu programa está certa, em outras palavras, você está fazendo a multiplicação e a soma de números complexos de acordo com as definições dessas operação pela matemática. Porém você deve lembrar que a soma de dois números complexos resulta em um número complexo e não um número Real ("float"), erro que você cometeu nas duas funções;

(2)Em C a definição de função tem essa forma:

```
    tipo_do_retorno     nome_da_funcao(declaracao de parametros)
     {
          /*comandos a serem preenchidos*/
     }
```

Usando seu código como exemplo e a definição de função em C, a declaração da função que soma dois números complexos poderia ser feita da seguinte forma:

```
complexo soma(float parteRealZ, float parteImagZ, float parteRealW, float parteImagW){
     /*comando a serem preenchidos*/

}
```

Perceba que na declaração dos parâmetros da função você só deve informar o tipo e o nome do parâmetro e.g "  float parteRealZ ", o acesso dos parâmetros utilizando por exemplo o '.' (ponto) não acontece na declaração da função;

Se olhar mais atentamente perceberá que você não está usando eficientemente o tipo que você criou(complexo) , porque na sua função soma você está recebendo 4 valores, porém essa mesma função poderia ser resumida para:

```
complexo soma(complexo z, complexo w){
    /*comando que serão preenchidos*/

}
```

Pode-se ler a função acima como "a função soma recebe dois argumentos, nomeados x e y do tipo complexo, e retorna um número complexo corresponde a soma desses dois números", esse mesmo raciocínio pode ser estendido para função multiplica. Em outras palavras, você pode criar uma função usando o tipo que você criou ;).

Última coisa, na linguagem C, você só pode retornar um único valor em uma função  e esse valor deve ser do tipo que você especificou na declaração da sua função, por exemplo, tome essa função mais simples:

```
int soma(int x, int y){
    int aux  = x + y;
    return aux;
}
```

Ela retorna apenas um único elemento do tipo int.

Além das alterações necessárias fiz uma alteração adicional no seu código,
criei uma função que exibe um número complexo.

Dessa maneira seu código poderia ficar assim:

```
#include<stdio.h>
/*#include<math.h>          nao foi usada*/ 

typedef struct NI {
    float real;
    float imag;
}complexo;


complexo soma(complexo z, complexo w){

    complexo aux_soma;

    aux_soma.real = z.real + w.real;
    aux_soma.imag = z.imag+ w.imag; 

    return aux_soma;
}

complexo produto(complexo z, complexo w){

    complexo aux_mult;

    aux_mult.real = z.real * w.real - z.imag * w.imag;
    aux_mult.imag = z.real * w.imag + z.imag * w.real;

    return aux_mult;
}

void printComplexo(complexo x){
    printf("%f %fi\n", x.real, x.imag);
}

int main(){
    complexo z,w,s,m;
    char op;

    scanf("%f %f %c %f %f",&z.real, &z.imag, &op, &w.real, &w.imag);

    if(op=='+'){
        s = soma(z, w);
        printComplexo(s);
    }
    if(op=='*'){
       m = produto(z,w);
       printComplexo(m);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Opa, dando uma olhada no seu código percebi algumas coisas, segue a lista a baixo:

- Declaração de Função: Em C, você não pode passar membros de estrutura
  diretamente na definição de uma função. Você precisa passar a
  estrutura inteira ou membros individuais, mas não como float z.real.
- Tipo de Retorno da Função: Você está tentando retornar dois valores
  (s.real e s.imag) de suas funções soma e produto, mas em C, uma
  função só pode retornar um valor. Uma maneira de lidar com isso é
  modificar a função para aceitar um ponteiro para uma estrutura
  complexo onde o resultado pode ser armazenado.

Corrigindo o código cheguei nesse resultado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
    float real;
    float imag;
} complexo;

void soma(complexo z, complexo w, complexo *resultado) {
    resultado->real = z.real + w.real;
    resultado->imag = z.imag + w.imag;
}

void produto(complexo z, complexo w, complexo *resultado) {
    resultado->real = z.real * w.real - z.imag * w.imag;
    resultado->imag = z.real * w.imag + z.imag * w.real;
}

int main() {
    complexo z, w, resultado;
    char op;

    scanf("%f %f %c %f %f", &z.real, &z.imag, &op, &w.real, &w.imag);

    if(op == '+') {
        soma(z, w, &resultado);
        printf("%f + %fi\n", resultado.real, resultado.imag);
    } else if(op == '*') {
        produto(z, w, &resultado);
        printf("%f + %fi\n", resultado.real, resultado.imag);
    }

    return 0;
}
```